# How do I print on a new line after every 6th number?

Tags: javascript, loops

So I'm making a loop that's supposed to print from 0-99 and it's supposed to make a new line after every 6th number like in the example below;

012345
678910

But right now it doesn't make a new line it just increases space between the "chunks" it's displaying. How do I get it to make a new line after every 6th number?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 6 && i <= 100; j++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += i;
    i++;
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += '\n';
  i--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A literal newline doesn't result in a visual newline in HTML:

```html
foo

bar
```

You need `<br>` instead:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 6 && i <= 100; j++) {
    document.body.innerHTML += i;
    i++;
  }
  document.body.innerHTML += '<br>';
  i--;
}
```

Or, I'd prefer to surround each block in a `<div>` - and you can increment the `i` only inside the inner loop to make the logic clearer:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100;) {
  const div = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  for (var j = 0; j < 6 && i <= 100; j++, i++) {
    div.textContent += i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a modulus to insert a `br` every sixth item - save you doing loops inside loops:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  document.body.innerHTML += i;

  if ((i + 1) % 6 === 0) {  // using i plus one as you start at 0
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering

> ***supposed to print from 0-99 and supposed to make a new line after every 6th number***

We need a PRE to not use a `<br>`

```js
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML =
  Array.from(Array(100).keys())
  .map(i => `${i.toString().padStart(3," ")}${(i + 1) % 6 === 0 ? '\n' : ''}`)
  .join("");
```

```html
<pre id="res"></pre>
```